# MS Access Moving records into fields

Tags: ms-access, field, record, denormalization

I have an ODBC connection to a database I don't own and can't change.  What I am looking to do is to make related records merge into one record.  The relationship is a 1 to many.

I have a student managment system and want to export a call out list which feeds an automated callout service (charged by Call).  I want to be able to call a house only once if there are multiple students living there.

Desired Call out file structure:

```
PHONE     Inst1                  Inst2                  Inst3
555-5555  John was absent today  Jane was absent today  Joe was absent today
```

as apposed to existing data:

```
PHONE     Inst
555-5555  John was absent today  
555-5555  Jane was absent today  
555-5555  Joe was absent today
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Another similar question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747021/flatten-relational-data-for-summary-export althought the accepted solution there requires you to choose an upper limit to how many students will be included on a single line.

Comment: Considering it's Access, I think we can safely assume he's using VBA.

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination was to use a crosstab query; however, that could get a bit hairy.

What about cutting some VBA code in a module to concatenate them together and then insert in the other table (something like the following - completely untested and probably broken somewhere)?

```
dim strAbsent as string
dim currPhone as string
dim lastPhone as string
Dim db As Database
Dim rstAbsent As Recordset
Dim rstAbsentReport As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rstAbsent = dbV.OpenRecordset("select * from Absent", _
                                    dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set rstAbsentReport = dbV.OpenRecordset("select * from AbsentReport", _
                                        dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

'...
do while not rstAbsentReport.EOF
    currPhone = rstAbsentReport("phone")
    lastPhone = currPhone 
    do while currPhone = lastPhone _
            and not rstAbsentReport.EOF
        strAbsent = strAbsent & ";" & rstAbsentReport ("comment")
        'Yes I know concatenating strings this way is terribly inefficient

        rstAbsentReport.MoveNext
        if not rstAbsentReport.EOF then
            currPhone = rstAbsentReport("phone")
        end if
    last
    rstAbsent.AddNew
    rstAbsent ("call") = strAbsent
    rstAbsent.Update
loop
'... clean up of recordset variables left as an exercise
```

Comment: I agree that this isn't the most efficient way of doing things, but if you're just generating data for a report, it will get the job done with minimal fuss. This is how I would approach it.